# Merge two data classes in Kotlin which have list of objects and can be nullable

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class in Kotlin like this which has list of objects and can be nullable:

```
data class exampleClass(
var list1 List<SomeObject1>?,
var list2 List<SomeObject2>?,
var list3 List<SomeObject3>?
)
```

```
data class SomeObject1(
 var id: String,
 var info: String,
)
```

```
data class SomeObject2(
 var id: String,
 var info: String,
)
```

```
data class SomeObject3(
 var id: String,
 var info: String,
)
```

If I have a list of exampleClass object like this:

```
[exampleClass(list1=[SomeObject1(id=1, info=Hello from someobject1 at 0), SomeObject1(id=2, info=Hello from someobject1.1 at 0)], list2=null, list3=null), exampleClass(list1=null, list2=[SomeObject2(id=2, info=Hello from someobject2 at 1), SomeObject2(id=3, info=Hello from someobject2.1 at 1)], list3=[SomeObject3(id=4, info=Hello from someobect3 at 1)]), exampleClass(list1=[SomeObject1(id=5, info=Hello from some object1 at 2), SomeObject1(id=6, info=Hello from someobject1 at 2.1)], list2=null, list3=null)]
```

I want to merge these 3 arrays of exampleClass into 1 exampleClass object where the lists should be merged as well. (in case both objects of lists are not null)

```
exampleClass(list1=[SomeObject1(id=1, info=Hello from someobject1 at 0), SomeObject1(id=2, info=Hello from someobject1.1 at 0), SomeObject1(id=5, info=Hello from some object1 at 2), SomeObject1(id=6, info=Hello from someobject1 at 2.1)], list2=[SomeObject2(id=2, info=Hello from someobject2 at 1), SomeObject2(id=3, info=Hello from someobject2.1 at 1)], list3=[SomeObject3(id=4, info=Hello from someobect3 at 1)])
```

Here the list1 from index 0 is merged with index 2.

I have tried this snippet of code:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.merge(other: T): T {
    val nameToProperty = T::class.declaredMemberProperties.associateBy { it.name }
    val primaryConstructor = T::class.primaryConstructor!!
    val args = primaryConstructor.parameters.associateWith { parameter ->
        val property = nameToProperty[parameter.name]!!

        (property.get(other) ?: property.get(this))
    }
    return primaryConstructor.callBy(args)
}
```

And I did this to merge:

```
var finalExampleClass = exampleList.removeAt(0)
exampleList.map(
 finalExampleClass = finalExampleClass.merge(it)
)
```

But this only merges the if the value of list in one object is null and in other it is not. With this I get the following output:

```
exampleClass(SomeObject1(id=5, info=Hello from some object1 at 2), SomeObject1(id=6, info=Hello from someobject1 at 2.1)], list2=[SomeObject2(id=2, info=Hello from someobject2 at 1), SomeObject2(id=3, info=Hello from someobject2.1 at 1)], list3=[SomeObject3(id=4, info=Hello from someobect3 at 1)])
```

In this case the list1 of index0 is replaced by index 2. But I want to merge the lists not replace them. If one of the lists is null then the merge is working fine as we can see for list2 and list3.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Does a null _mean_ anything different from an empty list here? If not, your code is likely to be a bit simpler if you make the lists non-nullable. (I think the only good reason for making them nullable would be if you had shedloads of these objects, most of the lists were empty, and you were worried about the memory usage or serialised size. But even that's unlikely to be a problem, coz the lists are not mutable, and so all the empty lists can be references to the same object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data class SomeObject1(
  var id: String,
  var info: String,
)

data class SomeObject2(
  var id: String,
  var info: String,
)

data class SomeObject3(
  var id: String,
  var info: String,
)

data class ExampleClass(
  var list1: List<SomeObject1>?,
  var list2: List<SomeObject2>?,
  var list3: List<SomeObject3>?,
)

val input = listOf(
  ExampleClass(
    list1 = listOf(
      SomeObject1("a", "0.1.0"),
      SomeObject1("b", "0.1.1")
    ),
    list2 = null,
    list3 = null
  ),
  ExampleClass(
    list1 = null,
    list2 = listOf(
      SomeObject2("c", "1.2.0"),
      SomeObject2("d", "1.2.1")),
    list3 = listOf(
      SomeObject3("e", "1.3.0")
    )
  ),
  ExampleClass(
    list1 = listOf(
      SomeObject1("f", "2.1.0"),
      SomeObject1("g", "2.1.1")
    ),
    list2 = null,
    list3 = null
  )
)
```

First version:

```
val result = ExampleClass(
  list1 = input.filterNot { it.list1 == null }.flatMap { it.list1!! }.ifEmpty { null },
  list2 = input.filterNot { it.list2 == null }.flatMap { it.list2!! }.ifEmpty { null },
  list3 = input.filterNot { it.list3 == null }.flatMap { it.list3!! }.ifEmpty { null },
)
```

Shorter version:

```
val result1 = ExampleClass(
  list1 = input.flatMap { it.list1 ?: emptyList() }.ifEmpty { null },
  list2 = input.flatMap { it.list2 ?: emptyList() }.ifEmpty { null },
  list3 = input.flatMap { it.list3 ?: emptyList() }.ifEmpty { null },
)
```

Comment: Any idea how to get them in a generic format like we call those function just once at one place instead of repeating it 3 times?

Comment: @aryakdangol I don't think that so. There might be shorter code possible, but the filtering, flattening, and setting to null if empty need to be done at some point for each of the three lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Kotlin `reduce` function in order to merge all your ExampleClass instances together.
Inside this reduce function, you then have to add the elements of your current ExampleClass to the "accumulated" one.

Here is an example:

```
val exampleClasses = listOf(ExampleClass(list1=listOf(SomeObject1(id="1", info="Hello from someobject1 at 0"), SomeObject1(id="2", info="Hello from someobject1.1 at 0")), list2=null, list3=null), ExampleClass(list1=null, list2=listOf(SomeObject2(id="2", info="Hello from someobject2 at 1"), SomeObject2(id="3", info="Hello from someobject2.1 at 1")), list3=listOf(SomeObject3(id="4", info="Hello from someobect3 at 1"))), ExampleClass(list1=listOf(SomeObject1(id="5", info="Hello from some object1 at 2"), SomeObject1(id="6", info="Hello from someobject1 at 2.1")), list2=null, list3=null))

val newExampleClass = exampleClasses.reduce { acc, current ->
    acc.copy(
        list1 = acc.list1.orEmpty().plus(current.list1 ?: emptyList()),
        list2 = acc.list2.orEmpty().plus(current.list2 ?: emptyList()),
        list3 = acc.list3.orEmpty().plus(current.list3 ?: emptyList()),
   )
}
```

When you see the content of the newExampleClass, you see the following:

```
List1: [SomeObject1(id=1, info=Hello from someobject1 at 0), SomeObject1(id=2, info=Hello from someobject1.1 at 0), SomeObject1(id=5, info=Hello from some object1 at 2), SomeObject1(id=6, info=Hello from someobject1 at 2.1)]
List2: [SomeObject2(id=2, info=Hello from someobject2 at 1), SomeObject2(id=3, info=Hello from someobject2.1 at 1)]
List3: [SomeObject3(id=4, info=Hello from someobect3 at 1)]
```

The only "issue" with this solution is in case you would like `null`value instead of an empty list in your merged ExampleClass instance.

If that's the case, then you can rework your ExampleClass instance with a `let`:

```
.let {
    it.copy(
        list1 = if (it.list1!!.isEmpty()) null else it.list1,
        list2 = if (it.list2!!.isEmpty()) null else it.list2,
        list3 = if (it.list3!!.isEmpty()) null else it.list3,
    )
}
```

Note: Try also to use `val` instead of `var` as much as possible, to guarantee the properties of your instance won't change in time. With this solution, you can use val in your ExampleClass but also in your Objects:

```
data class SomeObject1(
    val id: String,
    val info: String,
)

data class SomeObject2(
    val id: String,
    val info: String,
)

data class SomeObject3(
    val id: String,
    val info: String,
)

data class ExampleClass(
    val list1: List<SomeObject1>?,
    val list2: List<SomeObject2>?,
    val list3: List<SomeObject3>?
)
```